# Help with Undefined index and Undefined variable

Tags: php

Could somebody help me with this problem. I just trasferred my PHP/MYSQL program to another computer (both are running XAMPP and on localhost) and now I got a massive amount of Undefined index and Undefined variable ERRORS. Could somebody explain me why?

All the variables are checked with isset and all the values should be OK, but I can't get anything to work as it is supposed to and then there are the Undefined index and Undefined variable ERRORS.

Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: Please show us an example output of the error messages and the corresponding line in your code.

Comment: If you still get errors, then obviously not everything is ok. Cure the cause and don’t just fix the symptoms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look here: 
[error-reporting](http://br.php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php)

You can try something like that (runtime):

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Or update php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Comment: Thumbs upping for the near duplicate post. :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your configuration on the first box had a lower error reporting level.

You can set that in php.ini or in your code via ini_set.

php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

php code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers help you fix the symptom, not the problem. You are not getting errors, just notices, it's a special error level that warns you of a possible problem, but does not stop execution.

Given php's nature of not needing to declare variables, it is very easy to make a spelling mistake in your code and spend yours tracking it down (I'm sure everyone has did it at least a few times). And there comes E_NOTICE to the rescue: it warns you whenever you're trying to use a variable that did not get set beforehand - helping you spot the typo.

Avoiding it is really easy, suppose you're checking the presence of a submit button in your post array to do form processing:

```
if ($_POST["submit"] == "submit")
```

in case it's a regular get request, that line will throw an E_NOTICE for "submit" being an invalid index in $_POST. Avoiding it is really easy:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "submit")
```

this checks for the array index existence first. PHP uses lazy evaluation, in this case it means stopping after isset() if it returns false - the check that would throw the notice won't get executed. Also: `isset` is not a function, but a language construct - thus being fast.

My personal preference is to have error_reporting set to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` on all developer machines, that way I get notified of every possible problem - including using deprecated language features.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your error_reporting in the PHP configuration file (php.ini) is set differently as on your old XAMPP configuration.